# Rails select form: displaying and using select form value before submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a multi step form for an order placement process. In it I have two selectors for shipping countries and shipping services. After selecting the country all shipping services are displayed for a given place and weight. When the order is placed everything is written to the model. All the shipping details process is done through a multistep form following Ryan Bates [#217 Multistep Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms?view=asciicast)

The shipping service selector is populated through a javascript ajax call after the shipping country has been chosen. I followed this two tutorials [Dynamic select boxes with Rails 4](https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/) and [Dependent country city state](https://forum.upcase.com/t/dependent-country-city-state/7038/2).

```
$(document).on("change", "#lands_select", function(event){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/carts/update_shipping/" + event.target.value,
    type: "GET"
  })
});
```

update_shipping.js.erb

```
$("#shippingservices_select").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @shippingservices)) %>");
```

_shippingservice.html.erb

```
<option value="<%= shippingservice.id %>"><%= shippingservice.name.titleize %></option>
```

In addition to this I would like to display the shipping cost related to the selection made in both selectors below the form together with the calculated total shipping cost.

The subtotal cost of the cart is calculated in the cart model and for the order in the order model.

How can I do this? Since both values have not been written to the order database yet I would have to display the resulting price of the second selector selection which is inside the shipping services table, but since the order has bot been written yet I cannot call it through the order instance variable. My guess is that I would have to do this adapting the ajax call, could that be? How would I have to do this?

What I have now is that the form is populated through json produced by the order controller's update_shipping action as far as I understand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the cost depends on something or it is just a column in shippingservices table?

Comment: @Vasilisa. Hey Vasilisa nice to hear from you. The shipping cost would be in a column in the shipping services table. All additional costs such as packaging will be already included in this value in the table. I would need to get this value and somehow add it to cart.subtotal, which is calculated in the cart model and display it on the shipping cart page as well as through the order create part of the order controller. Once I submit the order I can rely on the value written to the order table, but during the process I think I need javascript + AJAX + a way do add the values.

Comment: I know how to do an ajax call to replace a div, but here I load on change data into a form which is something else. To combine the two is currently beyond what I am able to do.

Comment: I suppose I would have to add another js function to the on change call of my existing ajax call, but I do not know how to use the value related to the selection in the second function. I hope I expressed myself clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass that column in data attributes:

```
<option value="<%= shippingservice.id %>" data-cost="<%= shippingservice.cost %>"><%= shippingservice.name.titleize %></option>
```

and then display via JS like

```
$(document).on("change", "#shippingservices_select", function(event){
  var cost = $(event.target).data('cost');
  $("#some_cost_div").html(cost);
  // maybe add to total etc.
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I got it almost working. With `[s.name.titleize, s.id, {'data-price' => s.price}] ` and `$(document).on("change", "#shippingservices_select", function(event){
  var price = $(event.target).data('price');
  $("#shipping_cost").html(price);
  // maybe add to total etc.
});` and `Shipping: €<div id="shipping_cost"></div>` he prints out `price` in the page. How can I get the value instead?

Comment: I checked and something strange happens. I get the data-price in the DOM loaded, but not in the partials fetched via ajax. Why could that be?

Comment: After refining the view for the update_shipping.js.erb by specifying all options for the  render action everything is working now and I can finally confirm the answer as working. Thanks very much for your help Vasfed I have learned something new!!!